# Parallel or series circuit in Delta-Wye transformation

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics

in the transformation from a Wye (star) to a delta (triangle) resistor network it is said that if we want to know the "resistance" between points $N_1$ and $N_2$ ($N_3$ should be disconnected) then

$R_\text{Y}\left(N_1, N_2\right) = R_1 + R_2$ - which is obvious to me, as no current flows towards $N_3$.

Furthermore it is

$R_\Delta\left(N_1, N_2\right)= R_\text{c} \parallel (R_\text{a} + R_\text{b})$

I unfortunately don't see why $R_a$ and $R_b$ are in series and parallel to $R_c$, if $N_3$ is disconnected (open). How can they be in series if disconnected by N3?

I am sure it is obvious, but I can't see the trees in the forest.

[image: delta wye circuit]

Comment: Go through [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) slowly and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I went through it beforehand. Exactly what is not obvious to me is used as starting point for the derivation.

Comment: Give [this page](https://spinningnumbers.org/a/delta-wye-derivations.html) a look.  The key is that to the external circuit the delta and wye are indistinguishable.

Comment: Same thing, first formula. Why are Ra and Rb in series, if N3 is disconnected? Thats my question everything else is fine.

Comment: See my answer.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I unfortunately don't see why Ra and Rb are in series and parallel to Rc, if N3 is disconnected (open). How can they be in series if disconnected by N3?

$N_3$ is disconnected from the external circuit, it is not an open point.  So, if you connect a source between $N_1$ and $N_2$, the current from the source will flow through the two paths (blue & green) i show below.  Make sense?

[image]

Now you can see that the equivalent resistance seen by the source is,

$$R_{EQ}= R_c \text{ }//\text{ } (R_a + R_b)$$

I'm using the symbol, $//$, to mean "in parallel with".